# How to request d3 data from service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I'm following the tutorial about how to create a chart using d3 : http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

To read data to be displayed using d3 I use  :

```
 d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
```

data.tsv is a local file but how can I read this data from URL ?

I'm thinking I need to use an ajax request  :

$.ajax({
  url: "\data\",
  context: document.body
})

but since its asynchronous how can I use this as part of d3 ?

Update : the data is now wrapped in a jQuery GET request : :

```
    $.get( "getData.do", function( data ) {
    d3.tsv.parse(data, type, function(error, data) {
```

Here is the format of the data :

```
letter  frequency
test title 6    221
test title 8    218
```

d3 is not rendering the bar chart and there are no errors reported to console. The data format is correct as the diagram is displayed correctly when read from file. Am I accessing the data correctly ?

Entire code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }


    .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
    }

    .bar:hover {
        fill: brown;
    }

    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }

    .d3-tip {
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 12px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    .d3-tip:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        content: "\25BC";
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style northward tooltips differently */
    .d3-tip.n:after {
        margin: -1px 0 0 0;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(formatPercent);

    var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d) {
                return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
            })

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    $.get( "http://getFile", function( data ) {

    d3.tsv(data, type, function(error, data) {
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

        svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", (width / 2))
                .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("text-decoration", "underline")
                .text("Article Read Count");

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)



    });

        function type(d) {
            d.frequency = +d.frequency;
            return d;
        }

    });



</script>
```

Comment: Fetch the data from wherever and use `d3.tsv.parse(datastring)`. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-tsv_parse

Comment: @Sacho thanks, please see question update

Comment: You need to do a lot more than just fetch the data and call parse. All parse does is convert data from a TSV format to a javascript object. From then on, you need to draw your chart axes and then use the whole d3 select->data->enter->append cycle. I'd post an answer with some sample code but I'd be practically copy-pasting it from the site you linked. If you're actually doing all of that, post your code so people can check what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Sacho ok I've posted the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.tsv` wraps the asynchronous request for you. That is, you can pass it a URL and it will create an AJAX request, send it off and parse it.

```
d3.tsv("http://www.example.com/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  // the code in here will be run when the asynchronous request finished
  // the data parsed from the TSV will be available in data
});
```

There is no need to use JQuery in addition. If you remove that call from your code, it should work fine.

Comment: yes that worked although I did try that earlier and did not get a response and no error message was displayed. Maybe an older version of the page was being cached. Thanks.